# Verify ID Number using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to verify the south african ID NUMBER.  I am not fluent with javascript.

I have the following code:

> The HTML and Javascript

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<title>the man</title>
<script>
    function Validate() {
        // first clear any left over error messages
        $('#error p').remove();

        // store the error div, to save typing
        var error = $('#error');

        var idNumber = $('#idnumber').val();


        // assume everything is correct and if it later turns out not to be, just set this to false
        var correct = true;

        //Ref: http://www.sadev.co.za/content/what-south-african-id-number-made
        // SA ID Number have to be 13 digits, so check the length
        if (idNumber.length != 13 || !isNumber(idNumber)) {
            error.append('<p>ID number does not appear to be authentic - input not a valid number</p>');
            correct = false;
        }

        // get first 6 digits as a valid date
        var tempDate = new Date(idNumber.substring(0, 2), idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1, idNumber.substring(4, 6));

        var id_date = tempDate.getDate();
        var id_month = tempDate.getMonth();
        var id_year = tempDate.getFullYear();

        var fullDate = id_date + "-" + id_month + 1 + "-" + id_year;

        if (!((tempDate.getYear() == idNumber.substring(0, 2)) && (id_month == idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1) && (id_date == idNumber.substring(4, 6)))) {
            error.append('<p>ID number does not appear to be authentic - date part not valid</p>');
            correct = false;
        }

        // get the gender
        var genderCode = idNumber.substring(6, 10);
        var gender = parseInt(genderCode) < 5000 ? "Female" : "Male";

        // get country ID for citzenship
        var citzenship = parseInt(idNumber.substring(10, 11)) == 0 ? "Yes" : "No";

        // apply Luhn formula for check-digits
        var tempTotal = 0;
        var checkSum = 0;
        var multiplier = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
            tempTotal = parseInt(idNumber.charAt(i)) * multiplier;
            if (tempTotal > 9) {
                tempTotal = parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(0)) + parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(1));
            }
            checkSum = checkSum + tempTotal;
            multiplier = (multiplier % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;
        }
        if ((checkSum % 10) != 0) {
            error.append('<p>ID number does not appear to be authentic - check digit is not valid</p>');
            correct = false;
        };


        // if no error found, hide the error message
        if (correct) {
            error.css('display', 'none');

            // clear the result div
            $('#result').empty();
            // and put together a result message
            $('#result').append('<p>South African ID Number:   ' + idNumber + '</p><p>Birth Date:   ' + fullDate + '</p><p>Gender:  ' + gender + '</p><p>SA Citizen:  ' + citzenship + '</p>');
        }
        // otherwise, show the error
        else {
            error.css('display', 'block');
        }

        return false;
    }

    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

    $('#idCheck').submit(Validate);
</script>
</head>
```

> The Body:

```
<body>

<div id="error"></div>

<form id="idCheck">
    <p>Enter the ID Number: <input id="idnumber" /> </p>
    <p> <input type="submit" value="Check" /> </p>
</form>

<div id="result"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I am not getting any error output. Please Assist

Comment: look at this page: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the entire code, you are missing the closing head tag after script, I ran it and it worked as far as displaying different error messages with that cleaned up.

Edit- also added compiled code below which has document.ready shorthand.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>the man</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {

    function Validate() {
        // first clear any left over error messages
        $('#error p').remove();

        // store the error div, to save typing
        var error = $('#error');

        var idNumber = $('#idnumber').val();


        // assume everything is correct and if it later turns out not to be, just set this to false
        var correct = true;

        //Ref: http://www.sadev.co.za/content/what-south-african-id-number-made
        // SA ID Number have to be 13 digits, so check the length
        if (idNumber.length != 13 || !isNumber(idNumber)) {
            error.append('<p>ID number does not appear to be authentic - input not a valid number</p>');
            correct = false;
        }

        // get first 6 digits as a valid date
        var tempDate = new Date(idNumber.substring(0, 2), idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1, idNumber.substring(4, 6));

        var id_date = tempDate.getDate();
        var id_month = tempDate.getMonth();
        var id_year = tempDate.getFullYear();

        var fullDate = id_date + "-" + id_month + 1 + "-" + id_year;

        if (!((tempDate.getYear() == idNumber.substring(0, 2)) && (id_month == idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1) && (id_date == idNumber.substring(4, 6)))) {
            error.append('<p>ID number does not appear to be authentic - date part not valid</p>');
            correct = false;
        }

        // get the gender
        var genderCode = idNumber.substring(6, 10);
        var gender = parseInt(genderCode) < 5000 ? "Female" : "Male";

        // get country ID for citzenship
        var citzenship = parseInt(idNumber.substring(10, 11)) == 0 ? "Yes" : "No";

        // apply Luhn formula for check-digits
        var tempTotal = 0;
        var checkSum = 0;
        var multiplier = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
            tempTotal = parseInt(idNumber.charAt(i)) * multiplier;
            if (tempTotal > 9) {
                tempTotal = parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(0)) + parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(1));
            }
            checkSum = checkSum + tempTotal;
            multiplier = (multiplier % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;
        }
        if ((checkSum % 10) != 0) {
            error.append('<p>ID number does not appear to be authentic - check digit is not valid</p>');
            correct = false;
        };


        // if no error found, hide the error message
        if (correct) {
            error.css('display', 'none');

            // clear the result div
            $('#result').empty();
            // and put together a result message
            $('#result').append('<p>South African ID Number:   ' + idNumber + '</p><p>Birth Date:   ' + fullDate + '</p><p>Gender:  ' + gender + '</p><p>SA Citizen:  ' + citzenship + '</p>');
        }
        // otherwise, show the error
        else {
            error.css('display', 'block');
        }

        return false;
    }

    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

    $('#idCheck').submit(Validate);
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="error"></div>

<form id="idCheck">
    <p>Enter the ID Number: <input id="idnumber" /> </p>
    <p> <input type="submit" value="Check" /> </p>
</form>

<div id="result"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is strange. I added the closing </head> but still get the same result. Did you change anything else by any chance?

Comment: I ran with my jquery version 2.1.3 i'll have this up temporarily: http://codepen.io/tylert/pen/VeOayv

Comment: I added the compiled code that i tested with to my answer.

Comment: Any possibility you could modify your example to display the error in HTML5 format ? For example an error information bubble popping up next to the text field

Answer (score 0):

There were two proposed solutions and both of them would work.
First to remove script from the head section. (I guess you both placed `</head>` in different places, and that's why for one of you the submit attached correctly but not for the other)

```
<HTML>
<head>

<title>the man</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script> //your code</script>
<div id="error"></div>

<form id="idCheck">
    <p>Enter the ID Number: <input id="idnumber" /> </p>
    <p> <input type="submit" value="Check" /> </p>
</form>

<div id="result"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the other to wrap all your code in

```
$(document).ready(wrapper);
function wrapper(){
    function Validate() {
      //your code
        return false;
    }

    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

    $('#idCheck').submit(Validate);
}
```

Why does the first solution work? First we render `<head>` so when your code is run

```
$('#idCheck').submit(Validate);
```

cannot be attached because the dom element does not exist yet. If we place the code in the  execution is delayed.
Why does the second solution work? We wait until all page is rendered; only then do we execute our function that contains the same event attachment (`$('#idCheck').submit(Validate);`).

Comment: I suppose there must be something with my computer. Are you also using jquery 1.1.12 ?

Comment: where did you get 1.1.12 version? Maybe you use 1.12.0 ? Edit: noticed it is indeed 1.12.0 and included this version and it worked.